# Color on text area

Tags: color

I have a web application that works as a word processor/text editor with a text area for main input. It is designed through CSS. What background color is best to encourage the user to concentrate on the work and improve productivity? Does using a linear gradient or radial gradient have psychological effect? This text area part is the most important part, so the coloring of the other parts are flexible.

Comment: This is a very vague question, the background color will depend on what font you color you use and how the color ties in with your application design

Comment: Typography will play a big role as well.

Comment: I would say to default it to white and if the user happens to select white as the color of the text, at that time, and only at that time allow a new option for the user to select a custom bg color so he can see the text he is typing.

Answer (score 2):

I think the background should be clean - just white, or maybe paper-like. You can give users some options to choose from. Some may prefer clean card, the others, ruled paper.

A great way to make users focus on writing would be creating a distraction-free interface for writing - minimize the elements not directly related to writing, make the iconography minimallistic and you can allow users to go full screen. Regarding background - if you provide full screen, you could also add a dark theme.

A good example to follow is Byword app: http://bywordapp.com/